# git push: pack-objects died of signal 9

Tags: git, github, git-push

On my Ubuntu server, I am trying to push changes to my GitHub repository. However, the command always gets stuck at 99% "writing objects." Before it had this same error, except it stopped at 19%  instead. Afterwards, it has always shown this error:

```
error: pack-objects died of signal 9.27 MiB | 4.76 MiB/s
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to "https://github.com/[username]/[repository].git"
```

(I have replaced my username with "[username]" and repository name with "[repository]" here for privacy)

I have tried:

- checking my firewall to see if it is blocking git
- looking at logs
- increasing window memory size
- increasing the Git buffer size
- commiting smaller files at a time (this has seemed to change the % at which it got stuck on)
- ufw allow 9418/tcp
- repacking

None of these have worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message and the steps you have already tried, it seems like the issue could be related to memory constraints or large files in your repository. Here are a few more suggestions to help you resolve the issue:

- **Check system resources**

  Make sure your Ubuntu server has enough free memory (RAM) and CPU resources available. You can use commands like top, htop, or free -m to monitor memory usage.
- **Split your commits**

  If you still experience issues, consider splitting your commits into smaller parts, especially if you have large files in your repository. Commit and push smaller chunks of changes, and make sure to not exceed the [file size limits imposed by GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github?platform=linux#about-size-limits-on-github).
- **Remove large files from history**

  If you have accidentally committed large files in the past, [you can remove them](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github?platform=linux#removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history) as well.